# Controlling the y-scroll bar based on browser window size

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

When i open my website the y-scroll bar is opened, i want it closed however i want it to open when the window is re-sized for it'll become useful. Any idea on how to do so?

I've put in the body CSS:

```
body{
overflow-y:hidden;
}
```

However it becomes hidden on full size and re-size.

Comment: How do you know it's not useful when the page is first loaded? That's why the browser is putting it there, after all...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *can* do what you've described, but I can't imagine why you would want to.

You do it by having `body` initially have a class with the rule you've quoted, and then remove it on resize:

CSS:

```css
body.no-vscroll {
    overflow-y:hidden;
}
```

HTML:

```html
<body class="no-vscroll">
```

JavaScript (in a `script` tag at the end of the document):

```js
$(window).one("resize", function() {
    $("body").removeClass("no-vscroll");
});
```

Note the use of [`one`](http://api.jquery.com/one) (rather than `on`), since we only need to remove the class on the *first* resize. `one` will remove the handler automatically the first time the event occurs.

Re your comment:

> it didn't work.. Now both on full-size and re-size there is no scroll bar

[Works for me](http://jsbin.com/siyeze). I suspect that you just haven't applied the above correctly to your page.

Separately, though, I did think of a possible issue: You may want to wait for `load` before processing `resize`, since `load` waits for all the images and such to load, and loading images might be causing a resize:

```
$(window).on("load", function() {
    $(window).one("resize", function() {
        $("body").removeClass("no-vscroll");
    });
});
```

[Live Copy](http://jsbin.com/yimolo)

But that wouldn't account for what you describe. (Not waiting for `load` would have the *opposite* symptom: The scrollbar appearing when the page first loaded, despite your attempt to suppress it.)

Comment: it didn't work.. Now both on full-size and re-size there is no scroll bar

Comment: man it worked using the load. Just one question, is there a  way to fulfill the following case:
1_ Window full size no scroll (done)
2_ Re-size, scroll appears (done)
3_ Going full-size again, scroll re-disappear ?

Comment: I would look into [media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries). Don't think in terms of "full size" or other, just think in terms of the user controlling the size of their browser, and your site reacting to the various sizes they choose.